# Generate CSS classes from database?

Tags: php, css, laravel

It's possible to define a main color and a secondary color (hex-codes) in my application, those are saved to the db.

The secondary color for example is used for links. I don't want to say `<a href="#" style="color: $fromDatabase">Text</a>` but instead `<a href="#" class=secColor>Text</a>` where `.secColor` has something like

```
.secColor {
    color: $fromDatabase;
}
```

I'm using Laravel btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include a .php file as a css by using following code:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.php">
</head>
<body>
<!-- stuff goes here -->
</body>
</html>
```

style.php:

```
<?php
  header("Content-type: text/css");
?>
//DB Query
.secColor{
   color: <?php echo $fromDatabase;?>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

Create new route rule:

```
    Route::get('style/generate.css', function ($id) {
    // take your color
    $data['firstColor']= Colors::where('alias', '=', 'firstColor')->get();
    ...
    return View::make('css.colors', $data)
});
```

And create new view in  resources/views/css/colors:

```
.firstColor{
    color: $colors['firstColor'];
}
```

And in your main views

I use this method for create js custom file